# Why are base-32 numbers usually not used in programming?

Tags: binary, hex, decimal, octal, base32

Usually, programming languages support binary, octal, decimal, and hexadecimal numbers. But, base-32 numbers are usually not used in programming. I never seen a code that uses base-32 numbers. Base-32 numbers are short. For example;

`010011010010`(binary)==`2322`(octal)==`1234`(decimal)==`4D2`(hexadecimal)==`16I`(base-32, shortest)

Base-32 number is the shortest.

Why are base-32 numbers usually not used in programming?

Comment: 32 is an odd power-of-2.  How about [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)? 1234 --> `TS`?

Comment: [Base32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base32) relates to  this question.